# How to test for type equality in Rust?

Tags: rust, metaprogramming

I need to test if two types are equal in `const fn`. Comparing the `TypeId` doesn't work:

```
#![feature(const_if_match)]
#![feature(const_fn)]
#![feature(const_type_id)]

const fn t<T1: 'static, T2: 'static>() -> bool{
    std::any::TypeId::of::<T1>() == std::any::TypeId::of::<T2>()
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0015]: calls in constant functions are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
 --> src/lib.rs:5:8
  |
5 |     std::any::TypeId::of::<T1>()==std::any::TypeId::of::<T2>()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Template specialization as in C++ does not work in Rust, as Rust doesn't have "templates specialization". So, is there any way to test for type equality in Rust?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using Rust nightly (which it seems like you are), you can use the unstable [`specialization`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) feature and some helper traits to do this:

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]

/// Are `T` and `U` are the same type?
pub const fn type_eq<T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized>() -> bool {
    // Helper trait. `VALUE` is false, except for the specialization of the
    // case where `T == U`.
    trait TypeEq<U: ?Sized> {
        const VALUE: bool;
    }

    // Default implementation.
    impl<T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized> TypeEq<U> for T {
        default const VALUE: bool = false;
    }

    // Specialization for `T == U`.
    impl<T: ?Sized> TypeEq<T> for T {
        const VALUE: bool = true;
    }

    <T as TypeEq<U>>::VALUE
}
```

[Example in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=15ad676b8935eac7c95a809d4bcbc7be)

Comment: The types need to be `'static`.

Answer (score 0):

another stable solution with abusing [auto-deref specialization](http://lukaskalbertodt.github.io/2019/12/05/generalized-autoref-based-specialization.html):

```rust
macro_rules! eq_type {
    ($a:ty, $b:ty) => {
        {
            use $crate::EqType;
            (&&&$crate::Wrap::<($a, $b)>(::core::marker::PhantomData)).eq_type()
        }
    }
}

struct Wrap<T>(::core::marker::PhantomData<fn(T) -> T>);

trait EqType {
    fn eq_type(&self) -> bool;
}

impl<A> EqType for &&Wrap<(A, A)> {
    fn eq_type(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

impl<A, B> EqType for &Wrap<(A, B)> {
    fn eq_type(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }
}

mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn as_eq() {
        assert!(eq_type!(i32, i32));
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn as_ne() {
        assert!(!eq_type!(i32, u32));
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work with generic functions.